# How to do sidecar container communication in an ECS task?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, sidecar, amazon-ecs-sidecar

I have an ECS task where I have the main container and a sidecar container. I'm creating the task on EC2 and the network mode is `bridge`. My main container needs to talk to the sidecar container. But I am unable to do so.

My task definition is:

```
[
     {
       "name": "my-sidecar-container",
       "image": "ECR image name",
       "memory": "256",
       "cpu": "256",
       "essential": true,
       "portMappings": [
         {
           "containerPort": "50051",
           "hostPort": "50051",
           "protocol": "tcp"
         }
       ],
       "links": [
         "app"
       ]
     },
     {
       "name": "app",
       "image": "<app image URL here>",
       "memory": "256",
       "cpu": "256",
       "essential": true
     }
]
```

The sidecar is a gRPC server.
To check if I can list all the gRPC endpoints if I do the following from my main app container, it does not work.

```
root@my-main-app# ./grpcurl -plaintext localhost:50051 list
Failed to dial target host "localhost:50051": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:50051: connect: connection refused
```

But if I mention the EC2 private IP, it works. e.g.

```
root@my-main-app# ./grpcurl -plaintext 10.0.56.69:50051 list

grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection
health.v1.Health
server.v1.MyServer
```

So it is definitely a networking issue. Wondering how to fix it!

Comment: Have you tried using `awsvpc` network mode? I'm not sure `bridge` mode allows communication using `localhost` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-networking-awsvpc.html

Comment: `awsvpc` mode limits me to map a container to only one host port. meaning I can't scale the containers on the same EC2 as `50051` will not be available then.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? in `bridge` mode you need to know which ports are available since they share the EC2 instance ENI. In `awsvpc` mode, each task gets its own ENI https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-ecs-introduces-awsvpc-networking-mode-for-containers-to-support-full-networking-capabilities/?nc1=h_ls

Comment: Gotcha! But the problem is I can't use the "linking" of containers if I have to use the `awsvpc` as mentioned here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_network . So I can't provision my other container as a sidecar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using `bridge` mode and linking, then you actually need to use link name as the address, instead of `localhost`. You would need to link the sidecar container to the app container (you are currently doing the opposite) and then use the sidecar's link name as the address.

If you were using `awsvpc` mode, then you would use `localhost:containerport` to communicate between containers in the same task.